# How do you spawn an arctic fox in Minecraft education edition?

Tags: minecraft-education-edition

I to want make a home for the arctic fox so how do you spawn one in education edition?

Comment: What have you tried? We need to know before we can give answers you could've already tried.

Comment: What is unclear about this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that on Bedrock Edition (education edition is based on the Bedrock Edition), you cannot summon the snow variant of foxes via commands, since Bedrock commands lack the ability to utilize most NBT values.

So all I could really recommend is that you find a cold biome such as cold taiga, tundra, ice spikes, or frozen ocean and use a fox spawn egg in there to manually spawn in a snow variant fox, then find a way to transport it to a desired location.

Answer (score 0):

Foxes have been recently added, and their spawn eggs can be found in the creative mode search.

Comment: Hi, do you mean you agree with the existing answers? It's unclear, since you say to agree with GG001, but then point out a spawn command wouldn't work.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know much about Education Edition, but I do know that you can find spawn eggs in the creative menu, and within those eggs is an arctic fox spawn egg.  If you have cheats enabled, you can put in ***/spawn arctic_fox*** and it will spawn it in.

Comment: im like 99.999% sure this is incorrect. I'm pretty sure there is no `spawn` command in edu (or at all) and `arctic_fox` isnt a thing, only fox